# $\mathbb{C}$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis

Can

> $\mathbb{R}^2 \simeq \mathbb{C}$ and because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete $\implies \mathbb{C} $ is complete

be an argument to show thaf $\mathbb{C}$ is complete? Or can you give me a proof please?

Comment: It depends what you mean by $\simeq.$ Hint: completeness is relative to a metric.

Comment: I say yes. But you should show that any Cauchy sequence $z_n \subset \mathbb{C}$ has a limit in $\mathbb{C}.$ Hint: real and imaginary parts.

Comment: You have to show they're isomorphic *as metric spaces* for that argument to work.

Comment: Yes eyeballfrog, this is what I meant.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, what mean that they're isomorphic at metric space?

Comment: That you preserve the metric/norm. So it would actually here suffice that they are isomorphic as normed spaces, and so showing that, if we call your iso $f$, that $x$ has the same norm as $f\left(x\right)$.